# Speed up booting time without losing choosing capability in grub

Tags: boot, hardware, grub2

to speed up my boot time, I would like to get rid of the grub timing, but I would like to still be able to choose between different OS. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: For the tweak what you could do is install Grub on two USB keys, one that boot by default on one OS, the other key boot by default on the other OS. And whenether you want to load into one OS you plug the right USB key. I don't know if that would work but it could be a way to do what you want.

Comment: the USB stick solution is just less practical than the boot with a grub menu, and not faster, that is not a solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes you can. the timing and other attributes can be edited in the file `/etc/default/grub`.

Just do the following:

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Change **GRUB_TIMEOUT=10** to **GRUB_TIMEOUT=0** for fastest loading without waiting for the Grub menu to appear. Now the thing is, if you want to see the menu again, when the pc is starting press <kbd>ESC</kbd> like crazy until the Menu appears. The Grub menu will always appear when you press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, does not matter if the time is at 0.
3. After changing the timeout, save it with the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and you'll be asked for the file name to be saved. Just hit enter which will replace the grub. You can exit the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
4. Update grub by running (you guessed it): `sudo update-grub` so the changes can be active after the next boot up.

For the customized power and reset buttons for what I know is not possible "yet" to assign it to the Grub Menu.

Comment: @Memes haha. I needed a good laugh today. Thanks friend.

Comment: shouldn't you use a timeout of **1 second** instead of 0? otherwise, the menu would be gone completely woudn't it?

Comment: @rubo77 You can still access the menu by leaving SHIFT pressed or ESC (Don't remember which right now). Or tapping at one of those.

Comment: One more comment here, now, my boot time is not an issue anymore (boot with newer hardware and SSD), I then came back to a timing of 5 seconds and install Burg to get a clean neat OS selection screen.

Comment: and if you have UEFI install, Burg won't work but rEFInd will

Comment: I'm not on Ubuntu, but I am using GRUB. When I set the timeout to 0, nothing allows me to use the menu. Not pressing rapidly pressing or holding down any of these buttons is helping: esc, down arrow, shift. I really would like to be able to set it to 0 as the boot feels a lot snappier for me that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
 GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

and
edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom/`, append

```
if keystatus -s ; then
    timeout=10
else
    boot
fi
```

rebuild:

```
 config grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if keystatus -s ; then timeout=10 else boot
fi
```

Note: Make sure to put that `fi`, on its own line(like above), under the rest; before issuing the commands below:

`sudo config grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

and `sudo update-grub` (...can't hurt)

Make sure you get no errors.

It works; when I hold down Left, or Right shift; *before* leaving my computers (an HP desktop) BIOS post screen. So,  is the first thing GRUB2 "sees".

There are still reports of some computers not working. I'd try this. Best wishes.

FYI: I'm on Debian 7 (Wheezy, and with my added Mate, only.)
I have LightDM installed, and text configured to autologin.
After post, and before this GRUB2 start, I'm 33 seconds to my Mate desktop; without further optimizing.

Thank you.

Comment: although the solution seems elegant, the explanation is not complete (where do I write the if statement?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to script this, you can use this to edit the file /etc/default/grub from the script:

```
# Speed-up Grub boot, but always show the boot menu.
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_TIMEOUT=[[:digit:]]\+/GRUB_TIMEOUT=1/g' /etc/default/grub
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT/#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT/g' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

This will set the grub menu countdown to 1 second